# What is the difference between USER() and SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_USER')?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

In an Oracle Database, what are the differences between the following:

- user()
- sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER')
- sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')

Are these also possible related values to whatever 'the current user' is?

- sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA')
- sys_context('USERENV', 'AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY')

I am specifically interested in which ones can change, what can change them, which ones can not change value, which ones have different values based on connection type, and which one(s) is(are) always the schema used to log into the database.

In most of my testing the values are always the same. The only exception would be when running the following to alter 'CURRENT_SCHEMA':

```
alter session set current_schema=<SCHEMA>
```

Doing following results in an error:

```
alter session set current_user=<USER> --even as sys/system, which is good I suppose
```

So there is some kind of security/rules around all of this. However there must be some reason behind having a SESSION_USER and a CURRENT_USER. I also suppose user() could be a shortcut to sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER'), but I could find no documentation on the matter.

Comment: session_user/current_user could be influenced by the usage of proxy users, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_USER=` is not valid syntax anyway: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/statements_2013.htm#i2277774

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the manual at: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions184.htm#SQLRF51825

#### CURRENT_USER

> The name of the database user whose privileges are currently active. This may change during the duration of a session to reflect the owner of any active definer's rights object. When no definer's rights object is active, CURRENT_USER returns the same value as SESSION_USER. When used directly in the body of a view definition, this returns the user that is executing the cursor that is using the view; it does not respect views used in the cursor as being definer's rights.

#### SESSION_USER

> The name of the database user at logon. For enterprise users, returns the schema. For other users, returns the database user name. This value remains the same throughout the duration of the session.

So there **is** a difference between SESSION_USER and CURRENT_USER especially when CURRENT_USER is used in a stored procedure or function.

I have to admit that I don't know what the term "enterprise user" means though.

Btw: there is a third one:

#### SESSION_USERID

> The identifier of the database user at logon.

Comment: Isn't `SESSION_USERID` to `SESSION_USER` the same as `CURRENT_USERID` to `CURRENT_USER` and `CURRENT_SCHEMAID` to `CURRENT_SCHEMA` ? the documentation isn't so clear... is it really a third one ? are there also a 4th and 5th ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade: at least `SESSION_USERID` and `SESSION_USER` have a different description (see above). If they were the same I'd assume Oracle would have written the same description.

Comment: Of course they're not the same - one is the identifier and the other is the name. But what about `CURRENT_USERID` and `CURRENT_SCHEMAID`? according to the documentation, all 3 starts with the same description (replace "name" with "identifier") as their partners. What am I missing ?

Comment: What about the function 'user()'? How does that relate to any of those values? Also I was under the impression that USERs == SCHEMAs in Oracle.

Comment: @AndrewMartinez: Quote from the manual: "*USER returns the name of the session user (the user who logged on)*" So it's the same as `SESSION_USER`. When creating a user, a corresponding schema with that name is created as well (that's when user == schema). But when you switch the current schema (`alter session set current_schema=...`) then `current_user` **<>** `current_schema`

Answer (score 3):

`sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_SCHEMA')` - The schema that is currently being used and as you already found out can be changed with `alter session`

`sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')` - The user that was used for authentication during the creation of the session and cannot be changed

`sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER')` - <strike>Pretty much like "session_user"</strike>  deprecated (at least according to the [10g documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm))
(editted according to @a_horse_with_no_name's answer and the reference he gave to the [11g docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions184.htm#SQLRF51825))

`sys_context('USERENV', 'AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY')` - The identity used for authentication, depends on the "AUTHENTICATION_METHOD".
from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm):

> - Kerberos-authenticated enterprise user: kerberos principal name
> - Kerberos-authenticated external user : kerberos principal name; same
>     as the schema name
> - SSL-authenticated enterprise user: the DN in the
>     user's PKI certificate
> - SSL-authenticated external user: the DN in the
>     user's PKI certificate
> - Password-authenticated enterprise user:
>     nickname; same as the login name
> - Password-authenticated database user:
>     the database username; same as the schema name
> - OS-authenticated
>     external user: the external operating system user name
> - Radius/DCE-authenticated external user: the schema name
> - Proxy with DN
>     : Oracle Internet Directory DN of the client
> - Proxy with certificate:
>     certificate DN of the client
> - Proxy with username: database user name
>     if client is a local database user; nickname if client is an
>     enterprise user.
> - SYSDBA/SYSOPER using Password File: login name
> - SYSDBA/SYSOPER using OS authentication: operating system user name

`user pseudo column` - I'm not sure, according to documentation I'd think it's like `CURRENT_SCHEMA` but apparently it's like `CURRENT_USER`

Answer (score 3):

There is an important note to take into account when using the `USER` function from PL/SQL. As I have [documented in this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/09/07/beware-of-hidden-pl-sql-to-sql-context-switches/), `STANDARD.USER()` is implemented as follows:

```
function USER return varchar2 is
c varchar2(255);
begin
    select user into c from sys.dual;
    return c;
end;
```

So, it delegates to evaluating `user` in the SQL engine, which leads to a hidden PL/SQL to SQL context switch. If you're doing that too often, e.g. from within a trigger, then that can turn out to be quite hurtful in a production system. Try to avoid calling `USER()` from PL/SQL, and use `sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`CURRENT_SCHEMA` is the schema that will be assumed if you name an object without specifying its owner.  For instance, if my `CURRENT_SCHEMA` is `SCOTT`, then `SELECT * FROM EMP` is the same as `SELECT * FROM SCOTT.EMP`.  By default, when I first connect to Oracle, the `CURRENT_SCHEMA` is the same as CURRENT_USER.

However, if I am connected as `SCOTT`, I can issue `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=JOE` and then when I do `SELECT * FROM EMP`, it is interpreted as `JOE.EMP` rather than `SCOTT.EMP`.  Of course, if I don't have the `SELECT` privilege on `JOE.EMP`, or `JOE` doesn't have an object named `EMP`, the `SELECT` will fail.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a performance difference between USER and using sys_context

```
declare 
  v_result varchar2(100);
begin
  for i in 1..1000000 loop
  v_result := sys_context('userenv','session_user');
  end loop;
end;
/

-- 2.5s

declare 
  v_result varchar2(100);
begin
  for i in 1..1000000 loop
  v_result := user;
  end loop;
end;
/ 

-- 47s
```

Also see 
https://svenweller.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/sequence-and-audit-columns-with-apex-5-and-12c/
and
http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2019/01/oracle-user-vs-sys-context.html