# I was to execute a trigger and that should be applied to all users except one user

Tags: oracle, triggers, plsql

I want to execute a trigger and that should be applied to all users except one user.

How do I write this?

Please provide a simple code example?

Answer (score 5):

```
if user != 'BADGUY' then
--  run this code
end if;
```

Comment: You may want to add `and sys_context('userenv', 'current_user') != 'BADGUY'` if you also want to prevent their definer's rights objects from calling the trigger.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11005177/409172

Answer (score 2):

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER <trigger_name>
 :
 DECLARE


 BEGIN

   --replace scott with the user you want to restrict 
   IF sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_user' ) <> 'SCOTT' THEN  
     --do what you want to do 

   END IF;

 END <trigger_name>;
```