# How to pass OLD, NEW and identifiers to EXECUTE in a trigger function?

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I'm starting and trying some things in a new database, and am encountering a problem. I'm new in PostgreSQL.

I'm trying to create a history for the change of values in a column of a users table. The idea is simple. Whenever there is an update, a new record is inserted in another table (which represents the history).

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS LOCA_APP.FUNC_HISTORICO_MOD_USUARIOS() CASCADE;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LOCA_APP.FUNC_HISTORICO_MOD_USUARIOS() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$ 
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO LOCA_APP.TB_MODIFICACOES (
        MOD_MOMENTO ,             -- Translated to: Moment
        MOD_VALOR_ANTERIOR ,      -- Translated to: Old value
        MOD_VALOR_ATUAL ,         -- Translated to: New value
        MOD_USUARIO ,             -- Translated to: User (ID)
        MOD_DADO)                 -- Translated to: Data (Column Name - ID)
    VALUES(
        now() , 
        OLD.' || TG_ARGV[0] || ' , 
        NEW.' || TG_ARGV[0] || ' , 
        '|| TG_RELID || ' ,
        (SELECT DAD_ID FROM LOCA_APP.TB_DADOS WHERE DAD_NOME ILIKE ''' || TG_ARGV[0] || ''') );';
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TRIG_HISTORICO_USU_ID ON LOCA_APP.TB_USUARIOS CASCADE;
CREATE TRIGGER TRIG_HISTORICO_USU_ID AFTER UPDATE OF USU_ID ON LOCA_APP.TB_USUARIOS
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE LOCA_APP.FUNC_HISTORICO_MOD_USUARIOS('USU_ID');
```

**Note:** `EXECUTE` comments were put to better understanding here. The original code does not have these comments.

The pgAdmin is telling me:

> ```
> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "old"
> LINE 9:   OLD.USU_NASCIMENTO , 
>           ^
> QUERY:  INSERT INTO LOCA_APP.TB_MODIFICACOES (
>       MOD_MOMENTO ,
>       MOD_VALOR_ANTERIOR ,
>       MOD_VALOR_ATUAL ,
>       MOD_USUARIO , 
>       MOD_DADO)
>   VALUES(
>       now() , 
>       OLD.USU_NASCIMENTO , 
>       NEW.USU_NASCIMENTO , 
>       22664 ,
>       (SELECT DAD_ID FROM LOCA_APP.TB_DADOS WHERE DAD_NOME ILIKE 'USU_NASCIMENTO') );
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function loca_app.func_historico_mod_usuarios() line 3 at EXECUTE
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "old"
> SQL state: 42P01
> Context: PL/pgSQL function loca_app.func_historico_mod_usuarios() line 3 at EXECUTE
> ```

I have a single schema named `LOCA_APP` in my database, and my PostgreSQL version is **9.5**.

Can anyone explain what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how your trigger function would work properly:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loca_app.func_historico_mod_usuarios()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
      'INSERT INTO loca_app.tb_modificacoes
              (mod_momento, mod_valor_anterior, mod_valor_atual, mod_usuario, mod_dado)
       VALUES (now()      , $1.%1$I           , $2.%1$I        , $3         , $4)
                                                            
              )', TG_ARGV[0])
   USING OLD, NEW, TG_RELID
      , (SELECT dad_id FROM loca_app.tb_dados
         WHERE  dad_nome = TG_ARGV[0]  -- cast? see blow
         LIMIT  1);

   RETURN NULL;  -- only good for AFTER trigger
END
$func$;
```

#### Major points

- Pass the special row values `OLD` and `NEW` as well as `TG_RELID` as ***values*** to `EXECUTE` with the `USING` clause. You may have to cast `TG_RELID` to a fitting data type. The table definition of `tb_modificacoes` is undisclosed. Or you really want something else here. See below.
  `$1`, `$2` and `$3` in the SQL string passed to `EXECUTE` refer to expressions in the `USING` clause, *not* to function parameters, which can be referenced with the same positional syntax in the function body *outside* `EXECUTE`.
- Concatenate your dynamic SQL command using [**`format()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT). Much cleaner and safer. Quote and escape *identifiers*, *code* and *values* properly! `%1$I` and `%1$L` are format specifiers for `format()`. [Read the manual for details.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)
- Correct case is required! Your convention to spell identifiers with upper case letters makes sense in Oracle, where unquoted identifiers are converted to upper-case letters. It's not useful in Postgres, where everything is folded to lower case instead:
- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)
- Don't use `ILIKE` in `DAD_NOME ILIKE 'USU_NASCIMENTO'`. Postgres identifiers are case sensitive. You *could* have multiple matching values in `dad_nome`. Use `=` instead and pass identifiers spelled correctly. And make sure `dad_nome` is defined unique. See below.
- Your comment says:  `MOD_USUARIO ,  -- Translated to: User (ID)`. But that's not what you pass. The manual:

  > `TG_RELID`
  >
  > Data type `oid`; the object ID of the table that caused the trigger invocation.

  You may want to use `current_user` or `session_user` instead. See:

  - [What is the difference between USER() and SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_USER')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002746/what-is-the-difference-between-user-and-sys-contextuserenv-current-user)
- You can remove `LIMIT 1` from the subquery if `dad_nome` is defined `UNIQUE`. Else you need to decide which row to pick in case of a tie - with `ORDER BY`.
- Trigger functions are *required* to terminate with a `RETURN` statement. Might as well be `RETURN NULL` for an `AFTER` trigger. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html)

  > The return value is ignored for row-level triggers fired after an
  > operation, and so they can return `NULL`.

Related:

- [How to pass NEW.* to EXECUTE in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408171/how-to-pass-new-to-execute-in-trigger-function/36415706#36415706)
- [Replace double quotes with single quotes in Postgres (plpgsql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288759/replace-double-quotes-with-single-quotes-in-postgres-plpgsql/37288895#37288895)

*Aside:* While you are new to Postgres you might want to use this kind of advanced dynamic SQL carefully. You need to understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

It is your use of EXECUTE here that's causing the problem. When you prepare the statement in the way that you have done OLD becomes a literal instead of being a variable that holds a row of data as it would be outside the preparation.

As I see it you need execute because you are doing this:

```
    OLD.' || TG_ARGV[0] || ' , 
    NEW.' || TG_ARGV[0] || ' ,
```

Is it really needed? can't you just use

```
    OLD.USU_NASCIMENTO , 
    NEW.USU_NASCIMENTO ,
```

and be done with it? This way you avoid the need to use execute and OLD and NEW will behave as rows.

Comment: I think it's not possible. I have a trigger for each modified column. So I need the column name with its old and new value. The intention is to persist which column has been modified, and store the previous and current value. :/

Comment: be that as it may, the question is what was the error with these statements and the answer is the use of execute and OLD. As for any other way of doing it, I suppose that will have to be discussed in a separate question