# Error from trigger function: ERROR: column does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I created a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.delete_user() 
 RETURNS TRIGGER AS $func$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('UPDATE public.user SET %I = %L WHERE state = %L', 
    "state", "active", "deleted");
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

 CREATE TRIGGER deleted_user
    AFTER UPDATE ON public.user
      FOR EACH ROW
      WHEN (OLD.state IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.state)
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE delete_user();
```

Than after running:

```
update public.user set state = 'active' where fullname = '1234'
```

I get error:

```
> ERROR:  column "state" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...UPDATE public.user SET %I = %L WHERE state = %L', "state", "...
>                                                              ^
> QUERY:  SELECT format('UPDATE public.user SET %I = %L WHERE state = %L', "state", "active", "deleted")
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function delete_user() line 3 at EXECUTE SQL state: 42703
```

This is how state defined in user table:

```
state text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active'::text,
```

I'm new to Postgres so I guess it's a syntax error?

Comment: `UPDATE public.user ... ` ? `user` is a reserved word.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter no, it's a table

Comment: When I delete public. I get ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user"
LINE 1: update user set state = 'active' where fullname = '1234'
               ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 8

Comment: Why do you want to update **all** rows in the table if the triggering statement only updates a single row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would *work*:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.delete_user() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('UPDATE public.user SET %I = %L WHERE state = %L', 
  'state', 'active', 'deleted');

  RETURN NULL;  -- or OLD (for AFTER trigger)
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Single quotes for string literals instead of double quotes (for identifiers). You don't need dynamic SQL for this and can simplify:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.delete_user() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
  UPDATE public.user SET state = 'active' WHERE state = 'deleted';

  RETURN NULL;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

While the syntax works now, it results in an endless loop and makes no sense as is. I am not sure where you are going with this.

Related:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)
- [How to pass OLD, NEW and identifiers to EXECUTE in a trigger function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358020/how-to-pass-old-new-and-identifiers-to-execute-in-a-trigger-function/37358595#37358595)

Aside: `public.user` works since the schema-qualification removes ambiguity, but the bare table name `user` always requires double-quoting: `"user"`. ***Never*** use reserved words like `user` as identifier.

Comment: OK, great. now I have this ERROR:  control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function delete_user()
SQL statement "UPDATE public.user SET state = 'active' WHERE state = 'deleted'"
PL/pgSQL function delete_user() line 5 at EXECUTE
SQL state: 2F005

Comment: A trigger function need to return something. See above.

Comment: Finally had a minute and added some more above.